# Trying to enter data into database called from database, using html dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

i am having issues trying to generate a query to collect a list of countries (countryName) from MySQL DB country table, put into a dropdown list in HTML, and then send it back to the database, but the info is going into the FK called countryID in my Users table.

WHat is the best way to do this? can't get my head around this query...

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's hard to help you debug without seeing your code/attempts. Have a look at [help], [ask], and [mcve]. They might help you to improve your question and attract additional help.

Comment: What query? We can't help you if you don't show some code.

Comment: SELECT `country`.`countryName`, `country`.`countryID`, `users`.`countryID` FROM `country` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `country`.`countryID` = `users`.`userID`

Comment: This selects the information i need, i want to display the country namer in the dropdown, and send the id to the users table

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT CountryName
            FROM country
            ORDER BY CountryName ASC";

    $countries = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$countries) {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    while ($countryRow=mysql_fetch_array($countries)) {
            $countryName=$countryRow["country_name"];
                echo '<option value="$countryName"> $countryName </option>';

    }
?>
```

Then write some script to CHECK that COUNTRY has been selected? Either with javascript OR with a submit button?

EDIT: I would ON SUBMIT check to see what the ID of the country is, and INSERT that INTO the MEMBER/PERSON/WHATEVER table you need

This will help get you started

Comment: Thank you very much, i will give it a go

Comment: You're okay man, I'll keep writing some script and send it your way.